# UISupportedInterfaceOrientations on application descriptor file on AIR

Tags: ios, flash, air

I am using AIR2.6 for an iOS application.

In the application descriptor XML file , when 
autoOrients is declared as false then only one orientation is available on iPad (landscapeRight, portrait). That leads to apple rejecting the application as stated here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1689/_index.html (Support both variants of an orientation.)

I tried to put the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations key on the iphone section but is not allowed , as stated in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/air_buildingapps.pdf (page 72).

Is there any workaround on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to enable auto orientation and then listen for Orientation_Changing events from the Stage object. If the new orientation is not one that you support, call the preventDefault() method of the event object:

```
stage.addEventListener( StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, onOrientationChanging ); 

public function onOrientationChanging( event:StageOrientationEvent ):void 
{ 
    if(/*Not an orientation we support*/) event.preventDefault(); 
}
```